# Oracle: update table where number column in a string variable

Tags: string, oracle, csv, plsql, sql-update

Here is what I want to do:

current table:

```
+----+-------------+  
| id | data        |  
+----+-------------+  
|  1 | max         |  
|  2 | linda       |  
|  3 | sam         |  
|  4 | henry       |  
+----+-------------+
```

I have a id_str=1,3,4

Mystery Query - something like:

```
UPDATE table SET data = 'jen' where id in (id_str)
```

resulting table:

```
+----+-------------+  
| id | data        |  
+----+-------------+  
|  1 | jen         |  
|  2 | lindaa      |  
|  3 | jen         |  
|  4 | jen         |  
+----+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from a list of `id`s given as a CSV string, say `:id_str`, you can do:

```
update mytable 
set data = 'jen' 
where ',' || :id_str || ',' like ',%' || id || ',%'
```

An alternative is a regex functions:

```
where regexp_like(:id_str, '(^|,)' || id || '(,|$)')
```

Both solutions work, but are rather inefficient. A much better solution would be not to pass the serch parameters as a proper list of values rather than a CSV string.